# Extracting strings from one long string

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I have a string like this

"[0.01,3.45],[5.674,8.712],[4.321,8.892],[3.412,6.781]"

I need to extract each pair of numbers so that each pair is a separate string in a String array

i.e. I want: 
{"0.01,3.45","5.674,8.712","4.321.8.892","3.412,6.781"}

This is the code I have:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
    String[] result = pattern.split(myString);
```

.. and I get {"",",",",",","}

I have tried some different regex expressions as well but they just gave me an array with ONE (long) string element which obviously something I don't want either

Is the problem the regex expression or should I be using different code?

Thanks.

Comment: Your Regex is not doing what you might expect. (Split takes the regex to split on, not the regex you want to keep)... Consider http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for starters, and then play arround on  https://regex101.com/ or on https://www.debuggex.com/ On a side node: This can be solved without regex easily.

Comment: Split on `],[` and proceed as you'd expect. Or wrap in `[]` and pretend it's json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not split on brackets and commas (`],[`)?

```
String myString = "[0.01,3.45],[5.674,8.712],[4.321,8.892],[3.412,6.781]";
// remove start and close brackets
myString = myString.substring(1, myString.length() - 1);
String[] result = myString.split("\\],\\[");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
// [0.01,3.45, 5.674,8.712, 4.321,8.892, 3.412,6.781]
```

Comment: If you want to get rid of the first opening "[" and last closing "]" from the result, try myString.substring(1, myString.length() - 1).split("\\],\\[);

Answer (score 0):

My answer is I think you should be using different code (i.e. not regexs). I would prefer to take advantage of the Json-like appearance of the data.

You should consider using a Json parsing library to parse the string into a java `List<List<BigDecimal>>` (as dognose points out the input as given is not actually json). Then you can concatenate the components of that object however you like and construct any necessary arrays or strings.

There are many examples of Json parsing libraries. Google Gson is the first example that comes to mind but you can try others and find your favourite.

Comment: The example is not valid JSON.

Comment: Good point - it could be made valid Json by surrounding with "["... "]", but at that point it becomes just as messy as the regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

The regex is correct. You need to use something like

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);

while(matcher.find()){
    result.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

`group(1)` gives you the first group of the regex (which is everything inside the parantheses). If you need an array as a result you can convert the list by `result.toArray()`

If you use Pattern.split, it will use the regex as the seperator, so you get everything between the matches, but not the matches itself.